# Python - Is this a BUG? Where same script is working in my Linux and even local system but not in others

Tags: python, windows-7, pyqt, python-2.7, pyqt4

This is the same script i used in my local system where it work exactly. The same script is using in another location where its also a same system same setup. But not working.

I can not find anything wrong myself on this. Any idea if its a Python Bug?

What it does runs for 24/7 and shows a simple Gui before 9AM and after 3PM (PC has 24 hour time mode not AM or PM) . But its not doing in long run. (in my local system its doing exactly). How do i resolve this?

```
import sys
import datetime
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Main, self).__init__(parent) 
    flags  = QtCore.Qt.Window
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    flags |= QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
    self.setWindowFlags(flags)     
    self.b = QtGui.QPushButton("9/15 open", self, clicked=self.close)
    self.c = QtGui.QLabel("", self)

  def myRun(self):
    while True:
      time.sleep(2)
      print "[Debug]: " + self.showNowHour() + " " + self.showNowMinute()      
      hour = int(self.showNowHour())
      minute = int(self.showNowMinute())
      if (hour>8 and hour<15):
        print "is open"
        self.hide()
      else:
        print "is close"
        self.show()

  def showNowHour(self):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now = now.strftime("%H")    
    return now

  def showNowMinute(self):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%M")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myapp=Main()
  myapp.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 0, 0);")
  thread = QtCore.QThread()
  thread.run = lambda myapp=myapp: myapp.myRun()
  thread.start()    
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Follow up**:

```
  1 import sys
  2 import datetime
  3 import time
  4 from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
  5 
  6 class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  7   def __init__(self, parent=None):
  8     super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
  9     self.b = QtGui.QPushButton("exit", self, clicked=self.close)
 10 
 11   def showNowHour(self):
 12     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")
 13 
 14   def showNowMinute(self):
 15     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M")
 16 
 17   def myRun(self):
 18     while True:
 19       time.sleep(2)
 20       hour = int(self.showNowHour())
 21       minute = int(self.showNowMinute())
 22       print "[Debug]: " + str(hour) + " " + str(minute)
 23       if (hour>8 and hour<15):
 24         print "is open"
 25       else:
 26         print "is close"
 27 
 28 if __name__ == "__main__":
 29   app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 30   myapp=Main()
 31   myapp.show()
 32   thread = QtCore.QThread()
 33   thread.run = lambda myapp=myapp: myapp.myRun()
 34   thread.start()    
 35   app.connect(app, QtCore.SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), app, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))
 36   sys.exit(app.exec_())
 37   while thread.isAlive():
 38     app.processEvents()
 39
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What, specifically, does it do that you don't expect?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Do you get an error message?

Comment: May be the system in new location may be in different time zone.try datetime.datetime.now() in python shell to verify it is running in the same timezone as your local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This possibly fails because you are calling GUI methods from a different thread. You should always perform GUI calls within the main thread (aka "GUI thread"), otherwise it is easy to run into problems.

Instead of a thread which sleeps for two seconds on every loop, replace it with a `QTimer` that fires every 2 seconds. Put something like this in your mainline:

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(myapp.myPeriodicRun)  # connect the "timeout" signal
timer.start(2000)  # call every 2 seconds
```

In your `Main` class replace the `myRun` method with:

```
def myPeriodicRun(self):
  print "[Debug]: " + self.showNowHour() + " " + self.showNowMinute()      
  hour = int(self.showNowHour())
  minute = int(self.showNowMinute())
  if (hour>8 and hour<15):
    print "is open"
    self.hide()
  else:
    print "is close"
    self.show()
```

Isn't it nice not to need threads!

Comment: Thanks. Since i switch my code to this its working perfectly. I am now 100% sure the Thread was causing my problem specially in Windows 7 home editions. It could be my code or could be Python it self too. Which was never clear to me nor by others.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your call to strftime() is failing you. I can't see any wrong with it, but it's the only logical conclusion. But I'm not sure why you are using strftime when you can directly access hour from the datetime object.

Try replacing the call to showNowHour with 'datetime.datetime.now().hour'. It returns an integer in the range of 24 hours

See http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects